# why plt.show() shows one extra blank figure

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I use python 2.7 and trying to plot a simple percentile bat chart.

I get the figure that i want, the problem is that, with it, when using plt.show() i get an extra blank image,

I tried plt.close(), plt.clf() and plt.figure() to create a clean plt object, this is my function:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.grid(True)
data = zip(*percentiles)

data = [list(i) for i in data]
tick_range = data[0]

ticks = [str(i) + "%" for i in tick_range]
tick_range = [x+2.5 for x in tick_range]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.bar(data[0], data[1], width=5)

plt.show()
```

the data (percentiles) variable is of the following structure [(i,v),(i,v)....] when i is a index, and v is a floating point value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that `plt.grid(True)` operates on the current figure and since no figure currently exists when you get to that line, one is created automatically. Then you create *another* figure when you call `plt.subplots()`

You should add the gridlines *after* you create your plots

```
plt.bar(data[0], data[1], width=5)
plt.grid(True)

plt.show()
```

Alternately, just call `bar` without calling `subplots` since `bar` will automatically create a figure and axes as needed.

```
plt.grid(True)
plt.bar(data[0], data[1], width=5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: ONLY when I execute `fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(17, 10))` and `plt.show()` gives me an additional blank figure already!? Using matplotlib version 1.5.3. What do I wrong!?